# Things to do when transitioning jobs

Tags: career-development, professionalism, new-job, job-change, knowledge-transfer

This is my first time to resign as an IT Application Developer and I will be starting to work with my new employer after the 30 days notice that I gave in my resignation letter.

I'm new to this situation and I need some tips what are the right things to do during job transition so that my current workmates will not get difficulties when I'm gone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good place to start is by documenting your current roles/responsibilities and any information relevant to each one.  As an application developer that might not include too much specific information, but if there are any server instances that you manage you might want to consider listing the hostname, login details, configuration info, and similar information for each one.

Similarly, if you're the keeper of any important developer account passwords (or details for any testing accounts, etc.) you should ensure that they are properly documented somewhere and that the accounts are transitioned over to the company if necessary.

If your company has a *password protected* wiki that would be a good place for storing this information.  Though check first in case they already have a policy about where this sort of information should be kept.

You may also want to discuss with your manager and see if they'd like you to set aside some time to help with interviewing and/or training your eventual replacement, or if there's any specific information they want to make sure you document.

Comment: In addition, it would be good to leave some documentation about the work you've done. It is very difficult to read someone else's code. So comments, class diagrams, workflow description would be very useful and appreciated.